# How to design a REST API to allow returning files with metadata

Tags: rest

Suppose I'm designing a REST API and I need the clients to be able to obtain files with metadata. What is a good way to design the resources / operations?

Some ideas come to mind:

- **A single resource (i.e. GET /files/{fileId}), which returns a multi-part response containing both the file and a JSON/XML structure with metadata.** I have a feeling that this is not a very good approach. For example, you cannot use the Accept header for the clients to determine if they want a XML or a JSON metadata representation, since the response type would be multi-part in both cases.
- **Two resources (i.e. GET /files/{fileId} and GET /files/{fileId}/metadata), where the first one returns the file itself and the second one a JSON/XML structure with metadata.** There can be a link from the metadata to the file. However, how do I send a link to the metadata along with the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using the second idea you presented. This is the strategy used by most of the major web drives (Box, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc). They often have a significantly different URL because they store content and metadata in disparate locations.

You can add a Link header to the file response with a link to the metadata. Link headers are described in [RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988). The set of currently-registered link relations is [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml). Off the cuff, it seems that the `describedBy` relation is appropriate here.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. As of Dropbox V2, the content endpoint returns the metadata as JSON in the `Dropbox-API-Result` response header.

Comment: @Tom V2 didn't come out until 4 Nov 2015, more than a year after my answer. I'm good, but I'm not that good.

Comment: Hahah my bad. But still, they _now_ also return the metadata in a header.

Answer (score 4):

I've had success with the following kind of API design.  This differs slightly from what you suggested in that the main resource just contains links to its components.

```
POST /file
Request
  <bytes of file>
Response
  Location: /file/17
  {
    "id": 17
  }

GET /file/17
  {
    "data": "/file/data/17",
    "metadata": "/file/metadata/17"
  }

GET /file/data/17
  <bytes of file>

GET /file/metadata/17
  {
    "type": "image",
    "format": "png"
  }

DELETE /file/17
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first Option is not at all a good choice because it violates following REST constraint.

**Manipulation of resources through these representations** under **Uniform interface** Principle.

> When a client holds a representation of a resource, including any
>   **metadata** attached, it has enough information to modify or delete the resource.

If you brake it. Your URL will not be consider as RESTful.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints) about it.

Comment: Could you please explain how the first approach would break this principle? Thanks

Comment: @DušanRychnovský -http://bitworking.org/projects/atom/rfc5023.html#media-link-entries