# REST API - files with metadata - how to submit them

Tags: api, rest

Suppose I'm creating a service to manage files with metadata. As already discussed in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25082289/1103412) here on SO, the preferred way would be to create two resources:

1. file (i.e. GET /files/{fileId}) - the binary file,
2. metadata (i.e. GET /files/{fileId}/metadata) - the associated metadata.

The question is - what's the best way to allow clients to upload files with metadata? How about the following approach:

1. POST /files - the client uploads the binary file, the service creates a new file resource and a corresponding new, empty (i.e. default values), metadata resource and returns the ID of the file resource (i.e. fileId).
2. PUT /files/{fileId}/metadata - the client sets up the metadata.

I see a drawback to this approach - let's say that some of the metadata are mandatory. With this flow it is possible that the client only uploads the file but does not fill in the metadata, thus leaving the data in an inconsistent state.

On the other hand, allowing the client to send both the file and the metadata at the same time seems odd, because it's two different resources.

How would you deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the other hand, allowing the client to send both the file and the
>   metadata at the same time seems odd, because it's two different
>   resources.

The content and the metadata might be represented as different resources in your server but they are closely related to each other and it makes no sense to create one without the other. For example there might be clients that only need the metadata so they can display a list of files or details about a single file. On the other hand you need the metadata so that clients could know at least the name of the file they download. So you need them both.

That's why it's best to upload the file/content and metadata in a single [multipart](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) http request. Uploading everything in a single request makes your system more consistent because it eliminates various cases where the content is uploaded but the metadata is not (or the other way around).

The multipart request is basically a request that has both metadata (as a string) and the content in its body. The only difficult part are the headers. Take a look at the link above for more info about the multipart requests and in addition you might want to find a class (or family of classes) that deals with the multipart headers for you (depending on you platform/language).

In addition - having the metadata and the content as different resources is beneficial for the clients - they might download only one of the two, sparing network traffic (time) in case of large files.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then what you propose is that the POST /files operation expects a multipart HTTP request that contains both the file and the metadata. Is that right? Shouldn't then the GET /files/{fileId} operation also return a multipart HTTP response? Thanks

Comment: You can use a GET /files/id for metadata and GET /files/id/content for the content (or the other way around - /files/id/metadata for metadata and /files/id for content) :)

Comment: Or you can make it the way you mentioned it - GET /files/id returns multipart with metadata and content.

Comment: There is actually no correct answer - it can be done in multiple ways. Think about what is easier to be used and what might cause more problems.